# Missing scikit-learn packages

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

When I try to run

```
import sklearn.linear_model
```

I get an error

```
    ~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone1\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\least_angle.py in <module>
     21 from .base import LinearModel
     22 from ..base import RegressorMixin
---> 23 from ..utils import arrayfuncs, as_float_array, check_X_y, deprecated
     24 from ..model_selection import check_cv
     25 from ..exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I did some digging, and it looks like I don't have the as_float_array package

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils.as_float_array'
```

I tried reinstalling, but no change.  What's going on?

Comment: Did you install with pip? I highly recommend uninstalling it and using `conda install scikit-learn` instead. Packages using extension modules are inherently difficult to build on windows.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be very specific to your IDE/environment. It will be easier to solve if you provide more details. You can try the following:

Are you able to run the following code?

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

Can you list the packages installed and see if sklearn is there?

```
pip3 list
```

Do you see the same problem in Anaconda alone, or when you run this in command line?

**Edit: possible solution**
This looks like an access issue.

1. If you are on Windows OS, remove Anaconda & re-install it in a common folder, instead of under admin controlled folders (for example C:\anaconda, instead of under C:\Program Files).
2. Launch a new terminal from Anaconda Navigator -> Environments, then run this code.

Comment: I can import just sklearn, but when I try to import sklearn.linear_model, I get an error.  My version is 0.20.3.  I see scikit-learn when I run pip list, although I actually use anaconda to install.

Comment: @Jack I saw the same issue happen in a new laptop recently. I will post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a `conda install` solves the problem:

```
 conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```

It happened to me, for `numpy`